# Flex 4.5 Mobile - Setting width of a StyleableTextField in Custom Item Renderer

Tags: flex4, flash-builder, flex4.5, itemrenderer

I am creating a custom item renderer for a list so that I can have multiple columns of data using several StyleTextFields.

I'm working on a mixture of MXML and Actionscript (as StyleableTextField can only be created through Actionscript).

However I'm having problems getting the widths to line up. The Actionscript I am using to set the width is below:

```
var id:StyleableTextField = StyleableTextField(createInFontContext(StyleableTextField));                
id.width = (itemContainer.width * 30/100);
id.htmlText = "Text Here";

var desc:StyleableTextField = StyleableTextField(createInFontContext(StyleableTextField));              
desc.width = (itemContainer.width * 70/100);
desc.htmlText = "Much longer text description goes here";
```

As you can see I'm trying to set the width based on the width of it's container (shown below).

I've also tried setting percentWidth and explicit widths however the columns still seem to have varying widths.

My MXML looks something like this:

```
<s:Group width="100%">
    <s:HGroup id="itemContainer" verticalAlign="middle" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" paddingTop="10" paddingBottom="10" width="100%" gap="10">
    </s:HGroup>
</s:Group>
```

The id column in particular seems unwilling to go any larger than it's predisposed width. The desc column which can be multiple lines works better but still doesn't stick to a single width across all of the rows.

**UPDATE:**

Trying what Alex has suggested I now have the following ActionScript code. Though it doesnt seem to be doing much.

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth : Number, unscaledHeight : Number) : void {
if (idno == null)
{
idno = createDisplay(data.idno);
}
super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
idno.width = (unscaledWidth * 30/100);
desc.width = (unscaledWidth * 70/100);
trace (idno.width);
trace (desc.width);
}

protected function createDisplay(value:String):StyleableTextField
{
var field:StyleableTextField = StyleableTextField(createInFontContext(StyleableTextField));
field.text = value;
itemContainer.addElement(field);
return field;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth : Number, unscaledHeight : Number) : void {
    super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
    id.width = (unscaledWidth * 30/100);
    desc.width = (unscaledWidth * 70/100);
}
```

Comment: I've added an edit to my original post, showing how I implemented the function you suggested but it had no visual impact. The trace shows the widths it should be using and they're correct however the screen doesn't reflect that.

Comment: After doing some more experimentation (adding some borders onto my textfields) I've found that the widths are actually changing however the items in my hgroup aren't auto repositioning even though I've tried settings autoLayout to true.